# Existence of a special set of q+2 points in the finite affine plane over $\mathbb F_q$

Tags: combinatorics, finite-fields, projective-geometry, affine-geometry

I am working in the finite affine plane over $\mathbb F_q$ with $q=2^n$.
Such a plane has $q^2$ points, $q^2+q$ lines, each line has $q$ points, and by a point is passing $q+1$ lines.
There are $q+1$ directions and $q$ lines in each direction.

Here is a drawing of the plane for $q=4$ with the 5 lines going trough the point $(0,0)$. We use that $\mathbb F_4=\{0,1,x,x^2\}$ and that $x^2=x+1$ for the computation. (Don't take care of the first coordinate...)

[image: Affine plane over $\mathbb F_4$]

I would like to know if there exists a set of $q+2$ points $\{P_1,...,P_{q+2}\}$ such that :

- No three of them are on the same line
- There are 2 by 2 equals to the same vector, i.e. $\overrightarrow{P_iP_{i+1}}=\overrightarrow{P_1P_2}$ for any odd $i$.

I know that the answer is no for $q=4$. Indeed, if such a set exists, you can without loss of generality assume that $P_1=(0,0)$, $P_2=(0,1)$, $P_3=(1,0)$ and $P_4=(1,1)$. But then all the other points are in some line $(P_iP_j)$.

I believe (and would be happy) that such a set never exists but I cant prove it. If it does not exists, what it the maximal number of points I can have with these properties ?

It is linked to the hyperoval notion in projective plane : indeed, if you add a ''infinite line" with $q+1$ points, each of them corresponding to a direction and you join the lines of the same direction to the corresponding point, you obtain $PG(2,q)$. A set of $q+2$ points with no three points on the same line in $PG(2,q)$ is an hyperoval and exists, but I don't know if the points can be 2 by 2 equals to the same vector...

Any help is welcome !

Comment: When $q=2$ the affine plane itself works by virtue of there not being any three collinear points. But that is probably not very interesting for you :-) Have you checked the known families of hyperovals listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oval_%28projective_plane%29)?

Comment: Not really : I just checked with one of them. But I need to have the negative result for any hyperoval and for any affine plane you can get by removing a line without any point. I don't really now how to translate the vectors equality in projective geometry. A paralleogram is something like 4 points such that the 3 pairs of lines generates by the points taken two by two are intersecting in the same point. Does this have a name ?

Comment: Regarding a projective formulation using parallelograms, based on your choice of basis: You can use $P_1\vee P_2$ to fix the $y$ direction. The line $P_3\vee P_4$ intersects that line at the point at infinity in the $y$ direction. $(P_1\vee P_3)\wedge(P_2\vee P_4)$ is the infinite point in $x$ direction, so together they define the line at infinity. You can require for every pair $P_i,P_{i+1}$ that their join passes through the point in $y$ direction, and that $(P_0\vee P_i)\wedge(P_1\vee P_{i+1})$ lies on the line at infinity as well. I use $\vee$ for “join” and $\wedge$ for “meet”.

Comment: I agree, but how it can help for my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You say that for $q=4$ the answer is no, but doesn't your drawing show an example where this is the case? The green dots seem to have this property... your error is that you cannot assume W.L.O.G. that e.g. $P_4$ is $(1,1)$, only that $(1,1)$ is some point in the set. If you number the points lexicographically as they appear on your drawing, your property is met.

If I understand your problem correctly, the answer to your question is always yes. Just take a hyperoval in $PG(2,q)$, take a line $L$ that is disjoint from it (this always exists) and consider that line to be the line at infinity. Pick an arbitrary point at infinity and consider the lines through it, each such line intersects the hyperoval in 0 or 2 points. This gives a pairing of the point so that all vectors of these pairs are parallel.